# CSS Not loading correctly in IE

Tags: html, css

My site looks great in Firefox but the complete style sheet does not seem to loading. IE 7 is only choosing some styles to display. Any help would be much appreciated!

http://lifeazure.com/decor.php

Comment: Your page has a lot of HTML and CSS errors. Try fixing these and then see if you still have issues: [CSS Validation results](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Flifeazure.com%2Fdecor.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) / [HTML validation results](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Flifeazure.com%2Fdecor.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Answer (score 1):

you have an error in your CSS, line 306

```
margin:0 5px 0 5px
 padding: 2px;
```

should be

```
margin:0 5px 0 5px;
 padding: 2px;
```

This is probably stopping a lot of the CSS loading for IE